# How to rename undeleted mp4 videofiles according to "encoded date"

Tags: files, batch-rename, mp4, metadata

I recovered deleted videofiles from sd-card and now I cannot sort them by date.

I can see "encoded date" with `mediainfo filename`.

How can I use the "encoded date" to sort videos, even rename them according to that date or better yet, rewrite "modified date" to file properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the line of output you have looks something like this (the date format does not matter):

```
Encoded date               : 2016-11-20
```

You could rename the files as their dates with a little script...

```
i=0; for f in *; do printf -v new "$(mediainfo "$f" | sed -nr 's/Encoded date\s+: (.*)/\1/p')-%02d.mp4" "$((++i))"; echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"; done
```

I am giving them a final number to ensure files with the same date don't end up with exactly the same name, which would cause some to be overwritten. New filenames will be `2016-11-20-01.mp4` etc or whatever the date format from "Encoded date" is for you. Remove `echo` after testing to actually rename the files. More readable version:

```
i=0
for f in *; do 
   printf -v new "$(mediainfo "$f" | sed -nr 's/Encoded date\s+: (.*)/\1/p')-%02d.mp4" "$((++i))"
   echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"
done
```

#### Explanation

- `i=0` start iterating from 0
- `for f in *` for all files in the current directory (replace with appropriate path or glob if necessary)
- `printf -v new` format the new name like this
- `$(mediainfo "$f" | sed -nr 's/Encoded date\s+: (.*)/\1/p')` extract the date info from the Encoded date field
- `-%02d.mp4" "$((++i))"` add a number and extension to the end of each filename
- `mv -v -- "$f" "$new"` rename the files